# QR code generator that has "alphanumeric characters" option?

Tags: qr-code

I tried to use online tools, like [google/qr_codes](https://developers.google.com/chart/infographics/docs/qr_codes#details) and 
[goQR.me](http://goqr.me/), but neither have an "[alphanumeric characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_Code#Storage)" option, only complete binary (UTF8 or ISO) character set. I need only a little alphanumeric (A-Z,0-9,-,/,etc.), so a string like "`http://bit.ly/1234`" (a string with `length=18`) can be expressed by a Version-1 (21 rows) QR-Code symbol.

I also try to install (Linux, PHP, Python, etc.) tools... And, to my surprise, no "alphanumeric" option! (only, indirectly, the "binary" option).

Examples:

1. Good: https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=250x250&cht=qr&chl=http://bit.ly/12&chld=L|1   Generates a symbol of "`http://bit.ly/12`" (a string with `length=16`) with a version-1 QR-Code. OK! The guide say "... can encode up to 25 alphanumeric characters", so 16<25, then espected to version-1.

   1.1 **Bad**: https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=250x250&cht=qr&chl=http://bit.ly/12&chld=M|1  (change L to M), generates a version-2 (25 rows) symbol.

   1.2 **Bad**: https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=250x250&cht=qr&chl=http://bit.ly/1234&chld=L|1  (change length from 16 to 18), generates a version-2 (25 rows) symbol.
2. Trying to programm it... bad... See http://phpqrcode.sourceforge.net/ , even when I programming, I can't select a real "alphanumeric" option! No *Version-1 symbol* can be generated (!) with this kind of tools.

Comment: See [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18699739/287948)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The QR alphanumeric set does not include lowercase letters. The [standard](http://www.iso.org/iso/iso_catalogue/catalogue_tc/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=43655)'s definitive but the the [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_code) lists the characters in the alphanumeric set.

Comment: Yes, the automatic detection works well, the only "hidden instrution" is "use upper to use alphanumeric"!! Ok, it works (!): https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=250x250&cht=qr&chl=HTTP://BIT.LY/1234&chld=M|1

Comment: OPS, problem: the string `HTTP://BIT.LY/1234567890`  have 14+10=25 characters, so, 24<25, the maximum for mode L Version-1... But this [google/chart instruction](https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=250x250&cht=qr&chl=HTTP://BIT.LY/1234567890&chld=L|1) not show a Version-1 symbol.

Comment: ... Perhaps a *google/chart* bug (!?) because [api.qrserver generates a version-1 symbol](http://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?data=HTTP%3A%2F%2FBIT.LY%2F12345678901234&size=250x250)... But *api.qrserver* have another bug (??) because show a version-1 symbol with the string [`HTTP://BIT.LY/12345678901234`](http://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?data=HTTP%3A%2F%2FBIT.LY%2F12345678901234&size=250x250), that have length=28>25 (!).