# Tools for QR-Code generation, not agree about standard limits?

Tags: api, qr-code

### Question

There are (standard) size limits for strings presented by a QR-Code. Typical limits:

- QR-Code of *Version-**1-L**-Alphanumeric*: *25 characters*.
- QR-Code of *Version-**1-M**-Alphanumeric*: *20 characters*.

and there are ***software tools*** that **transforms a input string into a image** of the corresponding *QR-Code symbol*. These tools MUST respect the standard limits... But when you test **any of these tools**, they not respect...

**They not agree about ISO standard limits?** There are "another ISO"? There are a *bug*, or a [risck of non-interpretation of symbols](https://code.google.com/p/zxing/) when using *maximum sizes*?

### Context (at 2013-09) and explanations

When dealing with [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18691139/287948), I was faced with a new problem: each tool have a different choice for size limits in the string for each *QR-Code-Version*.

If all *QR-Code generator tool* cumply the "QR-Code standard", [ISO/IEC 18004:2006](http://raidenii.net/files/datasheets/misc/qr_code.pdf%E2%80%8E), **Table 7**, "Number of symbol characters and input data capacity"; all  the tools MUST render symbols as stated by ISO standard.
Examples:

- string `HTTP://BIT.LY/1234567890` have 14+10=24 characters, so, 24<25, the maximum for *Alphanumeric Mode-**L** Version-**1***.

  - *googleapis/chart/qr*: ok with [123456789](https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=250x250&cht=qr&chl=HTTP://BIT.LY/123456789&chld=L|1) but FAILS with [1234567890](https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=250x250&cht=qr&chl=HTTP://BIT.LY/1234567890&chld=L|1).
  - *api.qrserver*: ok with [1234567890](http://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?data=HTTP%3A%2F%2FBIT.LY%2F1234567890&size=250x250) (good!) but FAILS with [12345678901234](http://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?data=HTTP%3A%2F%2FBIT.LY%2F12345678901234&size=250x250) -- because have 14+14=28 characters, so, 28>25.
- string `HTTP://BIT.LY/12345` have 14+5=19 characters, so, 19<20, the maximum for *Alphanumeric Mode-**M** Version-**1***.

  - *googleapis/chart/qr*: ok with [1234](https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=250x250&cht=qr&chl=HTTP://BIT.LY/1234&chld=M|1) but FAILS with [12345](https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=250x250&cht=qr&chl=HTTP://BIT.LY/12345&chld=M|1).
  - *api.qrserver*: ok with [1234](http://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?data=HTTP%3A%2F%2FBIT.LY%2F1234&size=250x250&ecc=M) (good!), and good also with [123456](http://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?data=HTTP%3A%2F%2FBIT.LY%2F123456&size=250x250&ecc=M) (remains Version-1), but fails with [1234567](http://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?data=HTTP%3A%2F%2FBIT.LY%2F1234567&size=250x250&ecc=M), because not changes to version-2 when have 14+7=21>20 characters.

... and so on, with many other QR-Code generator (ex. [phpqrcode](http://phpqrcode.sourceforge.net/#demo) fails more!)  and Version-1 limits.

**That is a generalized bug?** Or my expections (about standard compliance and QR-Code Generators behaviour) are wrong?

PS: until now, for my point of view, there are a lack of (ISO) standard compliance in the tools.

---

#### Glossary

- *QR-Code Generation Tool*: any, online or offline, software tool that generate a QR-Code of a string, suppling as input the string and some parameters (typically version, EPS, charset and image size).
- *Encodable character set*:

  - 8-bit byte data (*binary*): a complete set, UTF-8 or ISO 8859-1 charsets. *Binary* is the usual default charset of *tools*, with the UTF8 option.
  - *alphanumeric* data: a set of ASCII 44 characters (digits `0-9`; upper case letters `A-Z`; nine other characters: (space), `$` `%` `*` `+` `-` `.` `/` `:`). Usually tools not have this option, but a "auto-detected" behaviour, [if the string is UPPER CASE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18691370/287948/), the charset is setted to alphanumeric.
- *ECL*: Error Correction Level of the QR-Code. ECL-L (Low) is 7%, ECL-M (Medium) is 15%.
- *Version **1-L** QR Code symbol*: a symbol with 21 rows and with low (L) ECL. When encoding *Alphanumeric* data, the maximum length of encoded string is 25 characters.
- *Version **1-M** QR Code symbol*: a symbol with 21 rows and with medium (M) ECL. When encoding *Alphanumeric* data, the maximum length of encoded string is 20 characters.

#### References

Other links for *ISO Standard Table-7* (copies and interpretations):

- [google.com/chart guide](https://developers.google.com/chart/infographics/docs/qr_codes#details).
- [ISO/IEC 18004:2006, only catalogue](http://www.iso.org/iso/iso_catalogue/catalogue_tc/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=43655), and copies: http://raidenii.net/files/datasheets/misc/qr_code.pdf‎
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_Code

Comment: Is the issue on the part of the QR generator, or on the part of the user who feeds non-compliant input into the QR generator? Misuse of a tool which does not purport to handle edge-cases is still misuse.

Comment: Hello Joe. Well, check if I understand your question... I am a user, I need a tool that meets the standards. The question is about *"what is wrong? I (a misuse)? The tool (a bug)? the standard (it is another)?"*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is one (not obsolete) ISO spec for QR codes, ISO 18004:2006. Most of what you observe is just lack of compliance. But there is one small part of the spec you are missing that explains the variance too.

First, why do some of these appear to encode too little info for a version and EC level? just a bug.

For example, the Google Chart implementation is quite old, not maintained, deprecated, and I know it has a few bugs. It was the basis for the encoder in http://code.google.com/p/zxing in 2008, and I know we fixed something like this a long time ago. zxing will not switch to the next version "too early" in your tests.

So how does `api.qrserver` appear to get *too much* info into a version 1 QR code? You're overlooking that you can switch modes in one QR code to further save bytes. This generator switch to numeric mode for the digits that end the string, and ends up saving enough to still fit into Version 1, EC level M, with 21 characters.

This is legal, although the optimization is not required. Choosing alphanumeric mode for the entire string is perfectly valid too, but will not yield the shortest possible encoding in some cases.

Comment: Thanks a lot Sean! Now I not feel alone, talking to myself about possible bugs :) Good contextualization about tool development and use of standards. Ops, You're the guy behind the  *ZXing Project*!? Thanks by your open-source work (!)

Comment: (bounty question) Can you *show one (or more) tool that comply the ISO standard*?  Perhaps [another ZXing-QR-Code-Generator](http://zxing.appspot.com/generator/), or similar tool, that works without bugs, and without "optimizations".

Comment: No that generator just calls the Google Chart server. I haven't tested any other generators. I don't know of any problems with zxing and you could write a generator that uses it if you needed to.